# Centre Two Buttons with Images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to centre two buttons but having no luck!

It also has a header image above the buttons within the HTML.

Here's my current HTML:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <img src=".jpg" style="width:700px;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" alt=""><div class="nav3" style="height:705px;">
  <span class="icons"><a href="https://twitter.com/" class="icons">
    <img src=".png" style="width:100px;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" alt=""></a>
  </span>   
  <a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/" class="icons">
  <img src=".png" style="width:100px;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" alt=""></a>

</div>
```

Comment: can you add a printscreen or something?

Comment: the div code is not completed, is not even closed...

Comment: what are you trying to do? can you create a mock?

Comment: also, read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will follow it in future

Comment: I basically have a header image and two buttons below it linking to amazon and twitter, both buttons have images. But the buttons are currently on two separate lines but I'd like them side by side...

Answer (score 0):

I revised your code and separate it the inline style from your html code.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  width: 700px;
}
div img{
  width:700px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav3 img {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/700x260" alt="">
  <div class="nav3">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x260" alt=""></a>
    <a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/"> <img src="http://placehold.it/640x260" alt=""></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, I set the width of `div` to `width: 700px;` and the place holder also contains the same width. Modify these width to suit your needs.